# Tooltip on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here it seems like this is what they say to do in the docs if I want to use just HTML to set a tooltip trigger but it only works on hover.

```
<div class='sample' data-trigger="click" data-toggle="tooltip" title="you clicked!">     </div>
```

heres my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fibubare/1/edit) as well

also from the docs:

**Options** can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-animation="".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="sample" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="you clicked!"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({trigger:'click'});
```

No change to your CSS

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/uAeqWUZB3W)